# Laravel 5.1 loop and merge Collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collect

I am trying to merge values together into one collection while I loop.

Here is my current setup

```
$collection = collect([]);

foreach($array as $item){

    $temp = $item->do_something;
    !is_null($temp) ? $collection->merge($temp) : null;
}
```

What $temp can hold is following:

`array['records' => $array, 'details' => $array]`

Now the closest I got was $array of $temp values but instead I would like to merge all those values into one collection. Instead of array of $temp arrays I would like one collection with Records, and Details.

Thanks

More details what I got visual:

```
[0]=> ['records' => $array
       'details' => $array]
[1]=> ['records' => $array
       'details' => $array]
[2]=> ['records' => $array
       'details' => $array]
```

What I would like is to merge all those into one

```
['records' => $array, 'details' => $array]
```